# Drop URI Segments with Mod_Rewrite. Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to drop 2 uri segments in codeigniter with mod-rewrite and still maintain functionality?

I don't want to use codeigniter routes because they don't seem to be what I need.

I have a long url: http://site.com/product/details/3/royal-blue-choir-stole

I want to use mod-rewrite to change to: http://site.com/royal-blue-choir-stole

Is it possible to retain functionality but re-write the URL, similar to how open source CMS systems do it?

My current htaccess file just has the code to remove the index.php from the url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?product/details/$0 [PT,L]
```